# Invoke DoubleClick Event on OneClick on Button in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

How can I invoke a Double Click Event in GWT when I click on button only once?

Answer (score 1):

What all you can do is, do not invoke that double event. Write a common method and do it in click handler.

```
function onClickAndDubleClick(){
  // TODO
}

onClick(){
common();
}

onDubleClick(){
common();
}
```

Comment: The button is not supposed to be clicked twice, only once.
So in method onClick I need to call double click somehow.
Thanks for reply.

Comment: This is the correct answer. You don't need to fire an event - you need to have the same consequences - i.e. trigger the same method as a result of a click and a double click.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a button:

```
Button button;
```

All you need to do in order to fire native double click event on it is:

```
NativeEvent nativeEvent = Document.get().createDblClickEvent(detail, screenX, 
    screenY, clientX, clientY, ctrlKey, altKey, shiftKey, metaKey);
DoubleClickEvent.fireNativeEvent(nativeEvent, button);
```

That's all. :)